# How do I prevent "standard folders" from recreating after restart?

Tags: 18.04

I've changed my Ubuntu 18.04 install language from English to Norwegian. Now, when you do that, Ubuntu makes some new "standard folders" (documents, pictures etc.) named in Norwegian. And that is great! But every time I reboot my PC, Ubuntu recreates the old folders in English.

That's not too much of an issue, since it does not delete or change the default folders back to the English ones. But it does mean I have to delete the extra English folders every startup to avoid cluttering. How can I stop Ubuntu from doing that every restart?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit your `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` file.

The default content is:

```
# If you want to change or add directories, just edit the line you're
# interested in. All local changes will be retained on the next run
# Format is XDG_xxx_DIR="$HOME/yyy", where yyy is a shell-escaped
# homedir-relative path, or XDG_xxx_DIR="/yyy", where /yyy is an
# absolute path. No other format is supported.
#
XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Desktop"
XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="$HOME/Downloads"
XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR="$HOME/Templates"
XDG_PUBLICSHARE_DIR="$HOME/Public"
XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="$HOME/Documents"
XDG_MUSIC_DIR="$HOME/Music"
XDG_PICTURES_DIR="$HOME/Pictures"
XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="$HOME/Videos"
```

Those are the only folders that will be automatically created.  Change the folder area to equal (`=`) the ones you created and would like to be your defaults.  Remove the ones you don't want.